# Is there any COVID-19 LIVE web-api available?

Tags: covid-19, covid-19-datasets

Is there a public (free) Web-API providing **live** COVID-19 cases evolution per country ?

By *live*, I mean the more recent data are available for the **current day**, not for the yesterday.

By Web Api I mean any web service providing JSON or other data format output with cases per country.

Feel free to contribute to the project: https://github.com/sdudnic/covid-19

Answer (score 1):

List from https://github.com/Bost/corona_cases/blob/master/web-services.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# A list of web services providing JSON data
# see also https://github.com/soroushchehresa/awesome-coronavirus
webServices = (

    # https://corona-api-landingpage.netlify.com/
    # https://github.com/CoronaAPI
    # https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/issues/1250
    # https://corona.ndo.dev/api/timespan?country=deu&time=year
    corona.ndo.dev

    # https://github.com/ExpDev07/coronavirus-tracker-api
    coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com

    # https://github.com/nat236919/Covid2019API
    covid2019-api.herokuapp.com

    # https://github.com/open-covid19/covid19-api
    api.opencovid19.com

    # https://bachbauer.eu/projects/corona/create_csv_de.php
    # provides downloadable csv files; not a proper web service
    bachbauer.eu

    # https://github.com/axisbits/covid-api
    covid-api.com

    # https://github.com/Laeyoung/COVID-19-API
    wuhan-coronavirus-api.laeyoung.endpoint.ainize.ai

    # https://www.micro-work.net/covid/ - as of now - work in progress
    www.micro-work.net

    # https://github.com/Omaroid/Covid-19-API
    covid19api.herokuapp.com

    # https://github.com/mathdroid/covid-19-api
    covid19.mathdro.id

    # https://github.com/NovelCOVID/API
    corona.lmao.ninja

    # https://github.com/amodm/api-covid19-in
    api.rootnet.in

    # https://github.com/rlindskog/covid19-graphql
    # GraphQL
    covid19-graphql.now.sh

    # https://github.com/isjeffcom/coronvirusFigureUK
    coronauk.isjeff.com

    # https://github.com/COVID19Tracking/website
    covidtracking.com

    # https://github.com/andreagrandi/covid-api
    # localhosting

    # https://micro-work.net/covid/jhutsconfirmedjson4.php/Swi/d:15
    # https://micro-work.net/covid/jhutsconfirmedjson4.php/US/d:15
    # TODO repo not found; see
    # https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/issues/492#issuecomment-601827214
    # wget --no-verbose https://github.com/matjung/covid
    # https://github.com/matjung/covid:
    # 2020-03-20 18:36:59 ERROR 404: Not Found.
    micro-work.net

    # coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com
)

for srvc in "${webServices[@]}"; do
    # mtr - a network diagnostic tool; speed tests and such
    mtr --report $srvc
done
```

For example, http://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com is currently up-to-date:

[image]

https://covidtracking.com/api/ claims to be updated daily. https://covidtracking.com/about-tracker/:

> We update the full dataset each day between 4pm and 5pm EDT, with limited updates as new information arrives.

Comment: I see different kind of API, but don't see one as of today data...

Comment: @Serge For example, http://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com is currently up-to-date

Comment: not it's not http://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/v2/country/GB today is 31, the update is from 30

Comment: you see from your image dt is "2020-03-30"

Comment: @Serge yeah it also says 11pm, so it was about 14 hours behind at the time of the API call, assuming it's GMT which I'm not sure. Anyway I just took one API at random, just use several apis and take the most recent.

Comment: yes, but I want today data

Comment: @Serge just call several apis and take the most recent. 14 hours ago mean today almost for half of the day.